# How can I encode a 2D matrix of booleans in the least amount of bytes?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, storage

I'm looking at this [ethereum smart contract](https://github.com/thousandetherhomepage/ketherhomepage/blob/master/contracts/KetherHomepage.sol#L88) that iterates over an area in a 2D bool matrix to reserve pixels. When looking at [a call to that ethereum smart contract for a 20x11 area](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x426be12bb020def009e967f2105d64ebeb880a26ff844321901afb5ccc3fb251), it used 0.0315 Ether ($9.36 on that date).

I made a Tezos smart contract with the same logic checks (except it's storing a `sp.big_map(tkey=sp.TPair(sp.TNat, sp.TNat), tvalue = sp.TBool)` instead of a 2D bool matrix) and I'm seeing really high burn fees. When running the same operation to reserve a 20x11 area, [the contract burned 3.68 Tez because it's storing 14741 bytes](https://better-call.dev/edo2net/KT1GzcZW6ga6FEpEZMM7jD3xdDwkeg3AHHqB/operations). If all I care about is setting the value of 220bits, then the storage requirement should only be 27.5 bytes which should bring down the burn fee to .006678 Tez.

What's the most efficient way to encode a 2D bool matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 20*11 area, you can use a bytes array of length round_up(20 * 11 / 8) = 28 bytes. The type for `bytes` is `sp.TBytes` in SmartPy.

However, there is no update in place operation so operations may be a bit complex and costly to write (but highly doable).

Comment: Any chances you have an example of how I could create that byte array? I'm trying this: `new_grid = sp.pack(int("".join(["0"] * 10000), 2))` but I'm having issues with unpacking it. It also appears as `new_grid=0x050000` when initializing it

Comment: You can do `sp.bytes("0x" + 28 * "00")`.

Comment: ok thanks. is this roughly what the code should look like when doing updates? https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmayZm6pnNV94EHWF5X64j8ucYo44ggnTo1iMMCGNbNF7G&k=c08aaad9f0aa009a1b6c

Comment: Probably but you should never add so many strings or bytes in n operations.

Anyway, I just thought of something. You can also use nats and bit operations. It may render the code much more efficient.

Comment: ok, I'll try using nats and bit operations

Comment: regarding the storage requirement from the Tezos contract I linked above, do you know roughly where the bytes are coming from? It's 14741/220=67bytes per grid cell. I'm assuming using a Pair of Nats is the most expensive part. Since each Nat is supposed to be arbitrary precision, how how many bytes does it allocate for each of them? Is each bool only 1 bit or more?